# TeamCity / BitBucket - Commit Status Publisher

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket, teamcity-9.0, bitbucket-api

We've got our source code up in BitBucket cloud and we're using TeamCity, with the "Commit Status Publisher" plugin.  I was using our repository url (for example https://bitbucket.org/test/test.git) as the "Stash base url", which worked for a while, but then I started getting a 404 just recently.  I tried using BitBuckets new build status api (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/buildstatus-resource-779295267.html?_ga=1.155356926.432767113.1452136822), but I get a 405 error.  Does anyone know which url I should be using and how to configure this in TeamCity?  Is there a better plugin I could be using?

Thank you in advance,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) and Bitbucket Server (formely known as Stash) use different API. Please install the latest version of the [Commit Status Publisher](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains_CommitStatusPublisher_91) plugin, it provides a dedicated support for Bitbucket Cloud.